# Command a number of words from the user and display those words as a list to the user

Tags: python, list, input, command, display

I want to write a code that takes a few words from the user and puts the words in the list.
How can I do this?
for example:
user write ( red blue gray black) and code display [red,blue,gray,black]

Comment: [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in one line:

```
print('[%s]' % ','.join(input().split()))
```

How it works:

- the input takes the input from user, returning it as string
- string split method separates the string into multiple single word strings
- the string join method, called on ',', joins the separate strings back with ',' between them
- Finally, the print function prints the string with [ and ] around it

Comment: Note that if you just want to put words in the list, and print the list (in your example, this would be `['red', 'blue', 'gray', 'black']`) you can do just `print(input().split())`, I've added the rest just to match your exact output.